# admin shipping account - shipping allowed only when status is preparing_shipment

Tags: admin, orders, shipping, permissions

I need to create an admin account that should be able to do **only** the following action:

- view orders that are in the *preparing_shipment* status
- change the status of the order to *shipped*
- insert the tracking code

I wasn't able just using the magento permissions, is there any method I can use?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would do something consistent with the native permissions of Magento, but it involves a bit of coding. The idea is to insert a new admin menu item in *Sales*, and we can call it *Prepare Shipment*. When clicked, it shows the same order grid that is pre-filtered for the status _preparing_shipment_. And when an order is clicked, it shows the custom order page that has the tracking code field and the button *Ship*.  Here's an etc/adminhtml.xml to get you started.

```
<config>
    <menu>
         <sales>
            <children>
                <prepare_shipment translate="title" module="msd">
                    <title>Prepare Shipment</title>
                    <action>msd/adminhtml_sales_order_prepareShipment</action>
                    <sort_order>15</sort_order>
                </prepare_shipment>    
            </children>
         </sales>
    </menu>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <sales>
                        <children>
                            <prepare_shipment translate="title" module="msd">
                                <title>Prepare Shipment</title>
                                <sort_order>15</sort_order>
                            </prepare_shipment>
                        </children>
                    </sales>                    
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

Note the module *msd* should be replaced with your own module name. The above will insert a menu item *Prepare Shipment* in the admin > Sales menu. It will also insert a resource under *Roles Resources* when you edit a role in admin > System > Permissions > Roles.

You'll need to create the controller action, custom order gird, and custom order page.